# SQL rotate rows to columns...dynamic number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

I have a dataset that has the below structure.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
  (
     Measure_ID  INT,
     measurement DECIMAL(18, 4)
  )

INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES
(1,2.3)
,(1,3.4)
,(1,3.3)
,(2,3)
,(2,2.3)
,(2,4.0)
,(2,4.5)
```

I need to produce output that will look like this.

```
1,2.3,3.4,3.3
2,3,2.3,4.0,4.5
```

Basically its a pivot on Measure_ID.  Unfortunately, there can be an unlimited number of measure_id's.  So Pivot is out.

I'm hoping to avoid CURSORS, but will if that turns out to be the best approach.

Comment: Sorry to be referencing my own blog here, but [this may help](http://www.jadito.us/2012/08/28/rows-to-column-header-using-dynamic-t-sql/). Also, it appears you are looking to go from rows to columns.

Comment: @Pondlife.  You are correct.  This is a close duplicate to those.  Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an unknown number of values, then you can use a `PIVOT` with dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' 
                        + QUOTENAME('Measurement_' + cast(rn as varchar(10))) 
                    from temptable
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by measure_id order by measurement) rn
                      from temptable
                    ) x
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT measure_id, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select measure_id, measurement,
                  ''Measurement_''
                    + cast(row_number() over(partition by measure_id order by measurement) as varchar(10)) val
                from temptable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(measurement)
                for val in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59342/4)

If you have a known number of values, then you can hard-code the values, similar to this:

```
SELECT measure_id, [Measurement_1], [Measurement_2], 
               [Measurement_3], [Measurement_4]
from 
(
  select measure_id, measurement,
    'Measurement_'
     + cast(row_number() over(partition by measure_id order by measurement) as varchar(10)) val
  from temptable
) x
pivot 
(
   max(measurement)
   for val in ([Measurement_1], [Measurement_2], 
               [Measurement_3], [Measurement_4])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59342/5)

Both queries will produce the same results:

```
MEASURE_ID | MEASUREMENT_1 | MEASUREMENT_2 | MEASUREMENT_3 | MEASUREMENT_4
==========================================================================
1          | 2.3           | 3.3           | 3.4           | (null)
2          | 2.3           | 3             | 4             | 4.5
```

Comment: Stunning bluefeet.  I swear, having stackoverflow around almost makes it so I don't have to think :-)  I think this will work.